# Pandas series: conditional rolling standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a Pandas series of random numbers from -1 to +1:

```
from pandas import Series
from random import random

x = Series([random() * 2 - 1. for i in range(1000)])
x
```

```
Output:
  0    -0.499376
  1    -0.386884
  2     0.180656
  3     0.014022
  4     0.409052
  ...
  995  -0.395711
  996  -0.844389
  997  -0.508483
  998  -0.156028
  999   0.002387
  Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

I can get the rolling standard deviation of the full Series easily:

```
x.rolling(30).std()
```

```
Output:
  0     NaN
  1     NaN
  2     NaN
  3     NaN
  4     NaN
  ...
  995   0.575365
  996   0.580220
  997   0.580924
  998   0.577202
  999   0.576759
  Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

But what I would like to do is to get the standard deviation of *only positive numbers* within the rolling window. In our example, the window length is 30... say there are only 15 positive numbers in the window, I want the standard deviation of only those 15 numbers.

One could remove all negative numbers from the Series and calculate the rolling standard deviation:

```
x[x > 0].rolling(30).std()
```

```
Output:
  2     NaN
  3     NaN
  4     NaN
  5     NaN
  6     NaN
  ...  
  988   0.286056
  990   0.292455
  991   0.283842
  994   0.291798
  999   0.291824
  Length: 504, dtype: float64
```

...But this isn't the same thing, as there will always be 30 positive numbers in the window here, whereas for what I want, the number of positive numbers will change.

I want to avoid iterating over the Series; I was hoping there might be a more Pythonic way to solve my problem. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask the non positive values with `NaN` then calculate the rolling `std` with `min_periods=1` and optionally set the first `29` values to `NaN`.

```
w = 30
s = x.mask(x <= 0).rolling(w, min_periods=1).std()
s.iloc[:w - 1] = np.nan
```

#### Note

Passing the argument `min_periods=1` is important here because there can be certain windows where  the number of non-null values is not equal to length of that window and in such case you will get the NaN result.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and super fast to calculate thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.Series(np.where(x >= 0, x, np.nan)).rolling(30, min_periods=1).std()
```

Output:

```
0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3      0.441567
4      0.312562
         ...   
995    0.323768
996    0.312461
997    0.304077
998    0.308342
999    0.301742
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You may first turn non-positive values into `np.nan`, then apply `np.nanstd` to each window. So

```
x[x.values <= 0] = np.nan
rolling_list = [np.nanstd(window.to_list()) for window in x.rolling(window=30)]
```

will return

```
[0.0,
 0.0,
 0.38190115685808856,
 0.38190115685808856,
 0.38190115685808856,
 0.3704840425749437,
 0.33234158296550925,
 0.33234158296550925,
 0.3045579286056045,
 0.2962826377559198,
 0.275920580105683,
 0.29723758167880554,
 0.29723758167880554,
 0.29723758167880554,
 0.29723758167880554,
 0.29723758167880554
...]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, after `rolling`, you want to calculate std of only positive values in each rolling window

```py
out = x.rolling(30).apply(lambda w: w[w>0].std())
```

```
print(out)

0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           NaN
4           NaN
         ...
995    0.324031
996    0.298276
997    0.294917
998    0.304506
999    0.308050
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```